# Documenting a REST interface with a flowchart

Tags: documentation, rest, flowchart

Does anybody have suggestions on creating a flowchart representation of a REST-style web
interface? In the interest of supplying thorough documentation to co-developers, I've been toying around in dia modeling the interface for modifying and generating a product resource:

[image]

This particular system begins to act differently with user authentication/resource counts, so before I make modifications, I'm looking for some clarification:

- Complexity: how would you simplify the overall structure to make this easier to read?
- Display Symbol: is this appropriate for representing a page?
- Manual Operation Symbol: is this appropriate for representing a user action like a button click?

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My apologies for the re-post. The main stackexchange site suggested this question was better presented on programmers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I feel Message Sequence Chart/Sequence diagram is better suited for documenting RESTful API interaction. What you have is a state diagram, while RESTful API by definition is stateless.

[image]

Comment: The server in a RESTful architecture is stateless, however, the system itself is not. State is stored at the client, and possible state transitions are encoded within the representation of a resource so that the client can initiate the transition to a new state by making a request to the server. I think a state diagram is quite effective at communicating the overall system state, even if it doesn't precisely document the requests and responses between the client and server components.

Comment: @Adam: you're right about overall system. But the question explicitly asks about documenting REST interface, not the whole system.

Comment: Thanks, vartec, the MSC effectively documents the REST interface in this instance. I'm still curious to hear improvements to this model's documentation of the client's state.

Comment: RESTful systems that implement the hypertext constraint cause the client to act as a state machine. I have found using state machine type diagrams to be a far more effective tool for documenting RESTful client/server interactions.

Comment: Is there possible to describe `if`-s and `while`-s in this diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I definitely think a state machine is the right way to document that interactions of a RESTful system.  However, I am still working on the right way to represent the [hypermedia factors](http://www.amundsen.com/hypermedia/hfactor/) in the diagram.  Here are a couple of experimental diagrams that I have done.

[image: Maze]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My two pennies on the subject, as I am working with this at the moment:

- focus on resources and their relations

  - and not on the action, and thus the HTTP method
  - when you follow a link, no matter if you did a GET or POST, your next possible states are dictated primarily by the current resource, and much less by the request's HTTP method

With that in mind:

- remove some obvious links (i.e. to self, to root)
- remove the relations' label if it just states "this [car] has a [owner]", where the source resource is car and the target resource is owner. It doesn't add anything
- an interactive graph can be of great help with a complex state diagram ([example](https://speakerdeck.com/andreineculau/rpc-to-rest-hypermedia?slide=17))